# Is there a way create an array with a variable length in c?

Tags: c, arrays, function

Is there any way (other than `malloc`) for creating an array with a size that the user inputs?

Comment: You need a compiler that supports it and the right options enabled. But be aware of the drawbacks of VLAs before you do it.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `malloc()` ?

Comment: i want to know if there is any alternative way of doing so.

Comment: It depends on which C you mean.

Comment: Well, you had better be very careful about your input then and understand (as @Mystical points out) the ramifications. IMO variable sized arrays are just a bad idea.

Comment: Take care, VLAs are generally allocated on the stack which is a sparse resource ...

Answer (score 6):

It all depends on the compiler.

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in `ISO C99`, and as an
>   extension **GCC** accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays
>   are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that
>   is not a constant expression. The storage is allocated at the point of
>   declaration and deallocated when the brace-level is exited. For
>   example:

```
 FILE *
 concat_fopen (char *s1, char *s2, char *mode)
 {
   char str[strlen (s1) + strlen (s2) + 1];
   strcpy (str, s1);
   strcat (str, s2);
   return fopen (str, mode);
 }
```

See [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a VLA (C99 defines what are called 'Variable Length Arrays').

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int use_a_vla (int n)
{
  int vla[n]; /* Array length is derived from function argument.  */

  vla[0] = 10;
  vla[n-1] = 10;

  return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
  int i;

  scanf ("%d", &i); /* User input.  */

  use_a_vla (i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have VLAs or `alloca()`, here is an extremely kludgy, but portable, stack-based technique:

```
int foo(int size)
{
    if (size <= 64*1024)
    {
        unsigned char   arr[64*1024];
        return bar(arr, size);
    }
    else if (size <= 1*1024*1024)
    {
        unsigned char   arr[1*1024*1024];
        return bar(arr, size);
    }
    else if (size <= 64*1024*1024)
    {
        unsigned char   arr[64*1024*1024];
        return bar(arr, size);
    }
    else
        return -1;       // Assume it's too big
}

int bar(unsigned char arr[], int size)
{
    ...your code goes here...
}

int maincode(int size)
{
    // Invoke bar() indirectly, allocating an array
    // on the stack of at least 'size' bytes
    return foo(size);
}
```

I don't particularly recommend this technique, but it will give you differently-sized blocks of memory allocated on the stack instead of the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is pedantic, but you can write your own heap management code and call your memory allocation function something other than malloc().  I hope this answer is amusing rather than annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to avoid `malloc` because you don't know about `realloc`.

Essentially, you should be trying to do roughly what the C++ vector does.  Once your array grows to a certain size, `realloc` it to twice its size.

`realloc` will grow your memory block if possible, and if not possible it will `malloc` a new one and copy the contents across.